# Hikari Data pool is shutting down in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, migration, connection-pooling, hikaricp

We are facing the below issue while migrating.

- Spring Batch 4.0.x from 3.0.x
- Spring Boot 2.0.x from 1.5.x
- Spring core 5.0.x from 4.3.x

After restarting the application, I could see after a min it throws the logs as `SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Shutdown initiated...`. 
But when we trigger the Job Hikari starts the new connections and working as expected. 
But I am not sure why the first connection is shutting down after a minute.

I understood that SpringBoot2.0 uses the Hikari for the DB Pool, but not sure why I am seeing Shut down info logs after one min of ideal time.

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-09-07 17:16:38,117 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=,msg="The following profiles are active: local" 
2018-09-07 17:16:39,495 -0700,threadId=1,level=WARN ,logger=HikariConfig.1081,msg="SpringBootJPAHikariCP - idleTimeout is close to or more than maxLifetime, disabling it." 
2018-09-07 17:16:39,495 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=HikariDataSource.110,msg="SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Starting..." 
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-09-07 17:16:39,695 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=HikariDataSource.123,msg="SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Start completed." 
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 07 17:16:39 PDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-09-07 17:16:40,002 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=Http11NioProtocol.180,msg="Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,010 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=StandardService.180,msg="Starting service [Tomcat]" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,011 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=StandardEngine.180,msg="Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,014 -0700,threadId=54,level=INFO ,logger=AprLifecycleListener.180,msg="The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/xxxxx/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,117 -0700,threadId=54,level=INFO ,logger=[/].180,msg="Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,310 -0700,threadId=54,level=INFO ,logger=ReceiverConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c1192a0.68,msg="creating activeMQConnectionFactory" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,786 -0700,threadId=1,level=WARN ,logger=Flyway.53,msg="Flyway.setCallbacks(FlywayCallback) has been deprecated and will be removed in Flyway 6.0. Use Flyway.setCallbacks(Callback) instead." 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,804 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=VersionPrinter.49,msg="Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 by Boxfuse" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,807 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=DatabaseFactory.49,msg="Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/invoicing (MySQL 5.7)" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,853 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=DbValidate.49,msg="Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.015s)" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,861 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=DbMigrate.49,msg="Current version of schema `invoicing`: 1.0.13.1" 
2018-09-07 17:16:40,862 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=DbMigrate.49,msg="Schema `invoicing` is up to date. No migration necessary." 
2018-09-07 17:16:43,166 -0700,threadId=1,level=ERROR,logger=,msg="[ThreadID-1] Warning: big time skew between machina and client: service=1536365803166 client=1536365760000 diffSecs=43" 
2018-09-07 17:16:44,425 -0700,threadId=1,level=WARN ,logger=JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.235,msg="spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning" 
2018-09-07 17:16:45,814 -0700,threadId=85,level=INFO ,logger=FailoverTransport.1052,msg="Successfully connected to ssl://qal.message-preprod.a.intuit.com:61617" 
2018-09-07 17:16:46,100 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=Http11NioProtocol.180,msg="Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]" 
2018-09-07 17:16:46,120 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=NioSelectorPool.180,msg="Using a shared selector for servlet write/read" 
2018-09-07 17:16:46,133 -0700,threadId=1,level=INFO ,logger=LateFeeProcessor.59,msg="Started LateFeeProcessor in 12.283 seconds (JVM running for 13.152)" 
2018-09-07 17:16:46,429 -0700,threadId=19,level=INFO ,logger=[/].180,msg="Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'" 
2018-09-07 17:17:47,868 -0700,threadId=93,level=INFO ,logger=HikariDataSource.381,msg="SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Shutdown initiated..." 
2018-09-07 17:17:47,876 -0700,threadId=93,level=INFO ,logger=HikariDataSource.383,msg="SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Shutdown completed."
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some issue and so far found that somehow spring issues shutdown command to Hikari thinking that its disposable bean.